# Prestashop, building the sub categories tree

Tags: php, tree, categories, prestashop

I'm trying to build a module for Prestashop 1.4, I need to retrieve and show the full category and subcategories list but I'm finding some difficulties:

This is my module logic:

```
class HyperFeed extends Module {

 function __construct(){ blablabla } 

 public function install(){ blablabla } 

public function _getCategories(){

    $version_mask = explode('.', _PS_VERSION_, 3);
    if ($version_mask[1]<5){$id_category=1;}else{$id_category=0;}       

    function getCategories($id_category){

        $sql = 'SELECT '._DB_PREFIX_.'category.id_category,name,'._DB_PREFIX_.'category.level_depth,'._DB_PREFIX_.'category.id_parent FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category
        INNER JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang ON '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang.id_category = '._DB_PREFIX_.'category.id_category
         WHERE id_parent = '.$id_category.' AND id_lang = 3';

        $contentTable = '<table>';
        if ($results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql)){
            foreach ($results as $row){


                $contentTable .= '   
                <tr>
                    <td width="3%"><input type="checkbox" name="footerBox[]" class="cmsBox" id="1_1" value="1_1"></td>
                    <td width="3%">'.$row['id_category'].'</td>
                    <td width="94%"><img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="../img/admin/lv1.gif" alt=""> &nbsp;
                    <label for="1_1" class="t"><b>'.$row['name'].'</b></label></td>
                </tr>';


                getCategories($row['id_category']);                      

            }
        }
        $contentTable .=  '</table>';


    }

    getCategories(1);
    $this->_html .= $contentTable;

} 

 public function getContent(){

$this->_html .='<form>blablabla';

$this->_getCategories();

$this->_html .='blablabla</form>';

}
    return $this->_html;
    }
```

All I get is a  "Undefined variable: contentTable", what Am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your `$contentTable` is defined within `getCategories()`, not `_getCategories()`.

Therefore on the following lines, it is considered not defined.

```
getCategories(1);
$this->_html .= $contentTable;
```

You can try doing the following:

Find:

```
$contentTable .=  '</table>';
```

Replace with:

```
$contentTable .=  '</table>';
return $contentTable;
```

Find:

```
getCategories(1);
$this->_html .= $contentTable;
```

Replace with:

```
$contentTable = getCategories(1);
$this->_html .= $contentTable;
```

This should properly define the variable within the `_getCategories()` function, by returning and assigning the `$contentTable` variable from the getCategories() function.

Comment: Thanks, that almost did the trick, now I get the results but are only showing the first level of categories and not any single subcategory, later with an echo it showed the full tree

Comment: Solved : I had to change the loop:

This: getCategories($row['id_category']);

For this: $contentTable .= getCategories($row['id_category']);

Now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

i found something else

```
public static function getCategoryTree($id_product,$id_lang){
                $root = Category::getRootCategory();
                $selected_cat = Product::getProductCategoriesFull($id_product, $id_lang);
                $tab_root = array('id_category' => $root->id, 'name' => $root->name);
                $helper = new Helper();
                $category_tree = $helper->renderCategoryTree($tab_root, $selected_cat, 'categoryBox', false, true, array(), false, true);
                return $category_tree;
            }
```

$this->getCategoryTree(null,$id_lang); 
and you have your category tree as prestashop backoffice associate tabs.
replace null by an $id_product and product categories will be checked.
Hope i'll help
sorry for my bad english i'm french